# Проблема с INSERT в таблицу БД(SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Начал изучать sql. Помогите разобраться с таким вопросом.
Есть вот такой insert запрос к таблице БД(SQL Server):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserData]
           ([Login]
           ,[PasswordId]
           ,[Address]
           ,[Number]
           ,[IsAdmin])
     VALUES
           (<Login, nvarchar(100),>
           ,<PasswordId, int,>
           ,<Address, nvarchar(100),>
           ,<Number, nvarchar(100),>
           ,<IsAdmin, tinyint,>)
```

`PasswordId` - FK к таблице `[dbo].[Password]`, где три столбца: Id(PK, авто инкремент), UserPassword и HashPassword.

Такой вопрос: 
вот есть приложение, к примеру, winForms, где есть интерфейс, позволяющий добавлять данные в БД. Что я больше всего не догоняю - ну вот есть `[dbo].[UserData]`, туда `INSERT` не проблема сделать, но есть там поле `PasswordId`, которое `FK`, и как я должен при `INSERT` узнавать необходимый индекс для этого поля? Прошу объяснить.

UPD: 
Скорее всего невнятно задал вопрос - попробую на примере.

Уже есть две таблицы(указанных выше) с заполненными данными. И вот я хочу вставить данные в таблицы. Как должна выглядеть команда `INSERT` в этом случае?

Comment: выполнить select на таблицу с паролями? (хотя не очень понятная для меня практика хранить пароли в отдельной таблице)

Comment: @tym32167, касательно размещения паролей тоже хотел узнать: есть пароль, который ввел пользователь, а есть его хэш-строка(создана через SHA384, если это имеет значение). Вот я и подумал, что, может быть, лучше хранить это в отдельной сущности. А по поводу вашего первого вопроса - нет, именно как я должен узнавать необходимый индекс в команду INSERT или вообще как она правильна должна выглядеть.

Comment: @tym32167 в описании вопроса добавил пример, мб это лучше даст знать, что я хочу понять.

Comment: Не очень понял вашу мотивацию про пароли. Сам пароль вам ни в коем случае нельзя хранить в БД, в БД хранятся только хеши паролей. Про селект я имел ввиду вместо `<PasswordId, int,>` писать `(select id from passwordTable where hash = @myhash)`

Comment: @tym32167, а где тогда можно хранить пароль пользователя, чтобы его подгружать при валидации с хэшем?

Comment: Пароли не хранят нигде - для этого и нужен хеш. Представьте себе, что вашу БД взломали и все данные утекли - утекут и пароли с ними. Но если вы храните только хеши, то хеши утекут, но получение паролей из хешей дело затратное. То есть процесс такой: юзер вводит логин и пароль, вы берете этот пароль, считаете от него хеш с солью, и сверяете, если ли такой юзер с таким хешем в БД

Comment: Смысл хеша в том, что очень легко посчитать хеш, имея пароль. Но в обратную сторону, то есть вычислить пароль, имея только хеш - это сложная, иногда невозможная задача. Потому если вас взломают и базу с хешами заберут, то на то, чтобы вычислить пароли юзеров по хешам у злоумышленников может уйти столько времени, что вы успеете заставить своих юзеров сменить пароли и работа злоумышленников уйдет на смарку.

Comment: Ну и вы должны понимать, что у каждого юзера должен быть уникальный пароль, то есть не должно быть такого, что одна и та же запись в таблице ПАРОЛИ связана с разными записями в таблице ЮЗЕРЫ. Это как раз и делает создание таблицы с паролями бессмысленной. Просто долбавьте поле с хешем пароля к ЮЗЕРАМ, а от таблицы с паролями избавьтесь.

Comment: @tym32167 отдельная таблица с паролями может понадобиться только в случае, если есть требования на обязательность периодической смены пароля и неповторяемость пароля при смене на новый.

Comment: @Bulson не имею ничего против хранения истории хешей в отдельной таблице. Я про то, что текущий хеш желательно хранить там же, где юзер\логин. А хранение истории это уже отдельная фича, никак не связанная с аутентификацией.

Comment: @tym32167 это да, я согласен. Но вопрос по сути не об этом. А о том как вставить данные в две таблицы связанные между собой внешним ключом.

Comment: @Bulson вопрос - классический пример XY проблемы. Вы можете ответить автору на его вопрос, а можете подсказать ему как решить его изначальную проблему, о которой он пока не знает.

Comment: @tym32167 это меня тоже озадачивает. Автор, вас интересует проблема хранения паролей? Или как записать данные в две таблицы связанные между собой внешним ключом?

Comment: @Bulson информация о хранении паролей была как никогда кстати, а если вы или кто-либо другой поделитесь мнением об используемой мной технологии хэширования паролей SHA384 - будет лучше некуда, а как сделать вставку данных в таблицы - основной вопрос:)

Comment: @Bulson в этом и сложность XY проблем. У автора есть задача - сделать авторизацию (проблема X). Автор думает, что он может это сделать, храня пароли в открытом виде в отдельной таблице (проблема Y). Автор спрашивает, как решить проблему Y, когда его главная проблема - X.

Comment: @sqlsqlsqlsql, сперва делайте вставку в таблицу `Password`, получите вставленный Id с помощью функции [SCOPE_IDENTITY](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql), положите в переменную, потом делайте вставку в `UserData`. Всё одним запросом к БД делается (в смысле request, а не query, которых, как раз, будет два). Пароли не хранят, прислушайтесь. Обособленное хранение информации, необходимой для аутентификации, в принципе, практикуется. Это может быть как отдельная таблица, так и отдельная БД на отдельном сервере аутентификации, всё зависит от требований.